# Custom title AND logo in PowerBI Report Server

Tags: powerbi, branding, power-bi-report-server

I have a Power BI Report Server 2017 to which I have applied a branding package, as per [this guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/branding-the-web-portal).

However I cannot find a way to have both a title *and* a logo at the top of the page.  Including `<Item key="logo" path="..." />` in `metadata.xml` successfully places the logo at the top of the page, but with no title.  Omitting this item results in the site name being displayed.

What is particularly annoying me is that the default (no branding package) *does* have both a logo and the site name...

Answer (score 1):

You can always add your title to your logo. Its not the greatest solution, but it is the only one unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a logo and a title.

If you put a logo, your way of doing it is correct :

```
<Item key="logo" path="logo.png" />
```

Otherwise, you can change the title in the **Site Settings, General, Properties** and then specify the name you want.